# Structures and Object creation

Tags: c++, arrays, object, structure

I am busy with a task and i have to create a structure and with that structure i have to create and delete an object.

Here is how i created the struct with a function inside.

```
struct Operation
{
    char op;
    double (*apply)(Operation*, double,double); // takes two doubles
}
```

That i perfectly understand. Now the object must be created.

```
Operation* Make(char op)
{
    Operation* ret = new Operation;
    ret -> op = op;
    ret -> apply = doit;//doit is a norther function 
    return ret;
}
```

I know the "->" operatic is the same as saying:

```
(*ret).op = op;
```

And the delete object;

```
void BrakeObject(Operation& o)
{
    delete o;
    o = NULL;
}
```

Will the function (apply) look the same as a basic function? 
Is this a array?

```
 Operation* ret = new Operation;
```

What is the object is it just a function?

Comment: You don't have a "struct with a function inside", you have a struct with a function _pointer_ as a member, one that points to a function that takes three arguments, not two. Your last function cannot compile at all: break is a keyword, and you can't delete references. You explanation of `->` isn't clear either... and I don't really understand your question at the end.

Comment: Hard to tell what you are asking here, but I suspect that really you want `double (*apply)(double,double); // takes two doubles
` What you wrote doesn't take two doubles, it takes two doubles and an Operation pointer.

Comment: The -> operator is to deference the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your vision does not match the task...

A)The structure
`char op;` can not be an "object". it is a "value", hm...
but `char *op;` may be ok?

B) Array.

```
Operation* ret = new Operation; //is this a array?
```

Nope. you have created a pointer to single value.

C) operator. this is wrong syntax

```
(*ret) op = op;
```

this will be ok

```
(*ret).op = op;
```

D) delete

```
void break(Operation& o)
```

it is wrong syntax, this will be ok

```
void BrakeObject(Operation*& o)
{
  delete o;
  o = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why the dynamic allocation? Why not simply:

```
Operation Make(char op)
{
    Operation ret = {op, doit};
    return ret;
}
```

Or, if you're using C++11, simply:

```
Operation Make(char op)
{
    return {op, doit};
}
```

In both cases, no need to manually delete anymore.

Also, why does `apply` take another operation? The comment says "takes two doubles", so:

```
double (*apply)(double,double);
```

Would make more sense to me. Also, where does `doit` come from? Wouldn't it make more sense to pass the apply function as a parameter, too? Here is the program with all the changes suggested:

```
struct Operation
{
    char op;
    double (*apply)(double, double);
}

Operation Make(char op, double (*apply)(double, double))
{
    Operation ret = {op, apply};
    return ret;
}

double add(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}

Operation op_add = Make('+', add);
```